# Combining bindings for Either type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, non-deterministic

For the following code, is it possible in Haskell to combine the bindings? Here is the original code:

```
Either1 a b = Left1 a | Right1 b

either1 :: Either1 () ()
either1 = Left1 ()

either2 :: Either1 () ()
either2 = Right1 ()
```

What I want is something like:

```
Either1 a b = Left1 a | Right1 b

either1 :: Either1 () ()
either1 = Left1 () || Right1 ()
```

Is this possible? If so, how Could this be done correctly? The above yells a lot about expected types.

I want to know if I can create a single binding that can result in either of the two options. I just want to know if this is possible in any way.

Comment: How do you want your `either1` to behave? Why do you want this? What feature are you asking for? You ask "Is this possible?" but it's pretty unclear to me what "this" is intended to be.

Comment: I wanted to know if I can create a single binding that can result in either of the two options. I just wanted to know if this is possible in any way. I figured the answer was no, but I am new to Haskell so just wanted to double check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One common technique for representing nondeterministic values is to produce a list with one element for each possibility. For example, the nondeterministic choice between `Left ()` and `Right ()` would be written this way:

```
whoKnows :: [Either () ()] -- read as: nondeterministic choice between multiple
                           -- possible values, each of type Either () ()
whoKnows = [Left (), Right ()]
```

Later, when you want to do a computation on this nondeterministic value, you can use the list's `Monad` interface. For example, supposing you have a nondeterministic computation:

```
couldBeAnything :: Either () () -> [Int] -- read as: nondeterministic function
                                         -- that takes an Either () () and
                                         -- returns an Int
-- implementation left as an exercise for the reader
```

You could combine the two like this:

```
soManyPossibilities :: [Int] -- read as: nondeterministic choice between multiple
                             -- possible values, each of type Int                
soManyPossibilities = do
    leftOrRight <- whoKnows
    couldBeAnything leftOrRight
```

You can also convert deterministic computations into ones that understand how to operate on nondeterministic values with `pure` or `(<$>)`. For example, if you had

```
soCertain :: Either () () -> Int
```

then you could write one of these (they mean the same thing):

```
fewerOptionsThisTimeMaybe :: [Int]
fewerOptionsThisTimeMaybe = do
    leftOrRight <- whoKnows
    pure (soCertain leftOrRight)
-- OR
fewerOptionsThisTimeMaybe = soCertain <$> whoKnows
```

Comment: wow, thank you for this. This is very helpful to myunderstanding

Answer (score 3):

No. Something of type `Either1 () ()` can be either `Left1 ()` or `Right1 ()`, but it is still a single, specific value.

---

Note that `Either () ()` is isomorphic to `Bool`. A `Bool` value is *either* `True` or `False`, not an indefinite superposition of the two.

```
to_bool :: Either () () -> Bool
to_bool (Left ()) = False
to_bool (Right ()) = True

from_bool :: Bool -> Either () ()
from_bool True = Right ()
from_bool False = Left ()

-- I leave it as an exercise to prove that
--  * to_bool . from_bool == id :: Bool -> Bool
--  * from_bool . to_bool == id :: Either () () -> Either () ()
```